# Node.js TCP server data loss

Tags: c#, node.js, sockets, tcp

I'm writting a local server in Node.js for a C# app.
In my C# code i have something like that:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    SendMessageToNodeOverTCP(i);
```

The messages are sent from a sep thread.
The expected output in node should be: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,...,998,999.
But what I get is this: 0,3,5,6,9,10,15,20,...995,997,998,999.

I'm pretty sure the problem is in Node.js side, and I'm not sure if its really losing data, or if i did something wrong...

My JS code is the following:

```
function OnData(p_data){
    LogData(p_data); //display the numbers in a custom gui
};

net.createServer(function (p_socket) {
    p_socket.on('data', OnData);
}).listen(p_port);
```

Comment: What does `LogData` do?

Comment: Its a custom method that only displays "p_data".

Comment: can you set `.setNoDelay(true)` to the server instance, and post back the results?

Comment: .setNoDelay(true) changed nothing >.<

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my own problem...

After a bit of reasearch I found that in TCP sometimes they stack packages togheter.
In node I was getting the data, passing it through a stream and creating a class from it.
What i had to do, is check if there was data left in the stream, and process that too...

Thx folks!